# C# BluetoothClient Failing To Send Data To Destination Device

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a problem. I can not send data with 32feet library for mobile device.
So far, I have tested several pieces of code.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("obex://" + arrayInfo[lstDevices.SelectedIndex].DeviceAddress.ToString() + "/" + ofd.FileName);
var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
request.ReadFile(ofd.FileName);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

The data is sent with the above code snippet, but I can not see how much information is being sent.
And I want to show the amount of data transfer with progressbar.

System gives following error with the code snippet below:

> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established
> connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

```
BluetoothClient client = (BluetoothClient)result.AsyncState;
client.EndConnect(result);
Stream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;

while (true)
{
  while (!ready) ;
  try
  {
    stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
    UpdateUI("Sended completed");
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    UpdateUI("error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```